# Why does Hadoop take so long to start with a large number of S3 paths?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hadoop2

I have a Hadoop job that has ~60k S3 input paths.  This job takes about 45 minutes to start.  The same job, with only ~3k S3 input paths starts almost instantly.

Why does having a large number of input paths cause the job to take so long to start?

Comment: Why does your post suggest there is a relation between Hadoop and S3? how are you accessing S3?

Comment: I'm not suggesting that there is a relationship between the two.  It just so happens that my input paths are all S3 paths.  I don't know if this happens with large numbers of HDFS paths.  For all I know, S3 is the problem.

Comment: When does the job take the information from S3? And how?

Comment: Instead of calling something like `FileIinputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path('hdfs://localhost/blah.txt'))`, I call something like `FileIinputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path('s3://my-bucket/blah.txt'))`

Comment: Well. I guess this means the files are downloaded and distributed **Before** the job starts. Why not get them from the map task itself? Only pass the path to each mapper, not the actual file.

Comment: That's not correct.  The files are downloaded during the map phase.  They're just downloaded from S3 instead of HDFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer has to do with how `FileInputPath.addInputPath(...)` is implemented.  If you take a look at the source [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/2.5.1/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/FileInputFormat.java#FileInputFormat.addInputPath%28org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job%2Corg.apache.hadoop.fs.Path%29), you'll see that its actually doing a string concatenation to save all of these paths to a file.  Calling `addInputPaths(...)` just calls `addInputPath`, so there's no savings there.  I ended up calling `FileInputPath.setInputPaths(Job, Path[])`.  This skips the 60k+ string concatenations by building that part of the settings file once.

As `climbage` mentioned, there will need to be 60k+ calls to S3 to build the splits.  It turns out that the S3 calls were taking less time than the string concatenation.  My jobs went from taking 45 minutes to start down to less than 20.

For those who don't want to go combing through the source, heres the implementation of `FileInputFormat.addInputPath()` in Hadoop 2.5.1:

```
public static void addInputPath(Job job, 
                                  Path path) throws IOException {
   Configuration conf = job.getConfiguration();
    path = path.getFileSystem(conf).makeQualified(path);
    String dirStr = StringUtils.escapeString(path.toString());
    String dirs = conf.get(INPUT_DIR);
    conf.set(INPUT_DIR, dirs == null ? dirStr : dirs + "," + dirStr);
}
```

and `FileInputFormat.setInputPaths()` in Hadoop 2.5.1:

```
public static void setInputPaths(Job job, 
                                   Path... inputPaths) throws IOException {
    Configuration conf = job.getConfiguration();
    Path path = inputPaths[0].getFileSystem(conf).makeQualified(inputPaths[0]);
    StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer(StringUtils.escapeString(path.toString()));
    for(int i = 1; i < inputPaths.length;i++) {
      str.append(StringUtils.COMMA_STR);
      path = inputPaths[i].getFileSystem(conf).makeQualified(inputPaths[i]);
      str.append(StringUtils.escapeString(path.toString()));
    }
    conf.set(INPUT_DIR, str.toString());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the first things that `FileInputFormat` does during MapReduce initialization is determine the input splits.  This is done by creating a list of every input file and its information (such as file size).  I imagine that 60k API calls to S3 for file information isn't fast.  45 minutes seems extraordinarily slow - there may be some rate limiting going on as well?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for reopening an old question but I recently came across similar issue.
And the core of it is that in your case Hadoop will make 60K calls to AWS

To work around this one can use wildcards

`FileInputFormat.addInputPath("path_to_a_folder/prefix*")`

this will generate only 1 AWS call to list the directory `path_to_a_folder` and then filter by the prefix

I hope this will help to whoever will find this question